# Save state of Fragment on orientation change (savedInstanceState)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Navigation Drawer with two fragments: Fragment0 and Fragment1
I want to save the state on orientation change.

**This is my code:** *(only the important part)*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int selectedPosition = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        selectItem(0);
        Log.e("savedInstanceNull", "gets called "+selectedPosition);
    } else {
        selectedPosition=savedInstanceState.getInt("fragmentposition",0);
        Log.v("Position get", ""+selectedPosition);
        selectItem(selectedPosition);
    }

}

 private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    switch(position){
    case 0:
        fragment = new Fragment0();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Futtermittelliste();
        break;

    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    selectedPosition = position;

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("fragmentposition", selectedPosition);
    Log.v("Position saved", ""+selectedPosition);
}
```

}

**LogCat:**

```
04-01 18:46:58.455: V/Position saved(2077): 1
04-01 18:46:58.515: V/Position get(2077): 1
04-01 18:46:58.555: E/savedInstanceNull(2077): gets called 0
```

The position (1) gets stored (first LogCat output)
Then the `else statement` of the `savedInstanceState` gets called and I retrieve the position (1) (second LocCat output)
But now, and I don't know why, the `if (savedInstanceState == null)` gets called again and this sets the `selectItem(0)` and not `selectItem(1)`

Do you have an idea why?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figuered it out:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null){
        selectedPosition=savedInstanceState.getInt("fragmentposition",0);
        selectItem(selectedPosition);
    } else { 
        selectItem(selectedPosition);
    }
```

This works. I don't know why the first method don't work but maybe I can help anyone with this solution